# Calculate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}\mathrm{d}x$ through the Guasssian integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The problem is to determine the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
through the Guassian integral:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

All that has occurred to me is integration by parts, which gives
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}\frac{-1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}x+2-\sqrt{\pi}.$$
However, it still seems far from the result we're looking for, and I get stuck. Please help.

Comment: [You'll need](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%2F%28x%2B1%2F2%29%5E2+from+0+to+infinity&dataset=) two [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function) [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $I = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx$ and $I_m = \int_0^\infty x^me^{-x^2}dx$ for non-negative integer *m*.Using taylor series tell us: $(x+\frac{1}{2})^{-2}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m(m+1)2^{m+2}x^m$ so we have: $$I = \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m(m+1)2^{m+2}\int_0^\infty x^me^{-x^2}dx$$On the other hand use integration by part for $I_m$ we have: $I_m=\frac{1}{2}(m-1)I_{m-2}$ and $I_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $I_0=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Now you can write $$I=\sum_{m=0}^∞(−1)^m(m+1)2^{m+2}I_m$$Also $$I_m = (\frac{1}{2})^{[\frac{m}{2}]}I_s\prod_{k=0}^{[\frac{m}{2}]}(m-(2k+1))$$ That *s* is 1 if m is odd and zero if m is even.
It Means that we have written *I* using $I_0$ and $I_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here I wonder whether applying Taylor series here is rigorous. Can you show rigidity?